# Zend framework 3 Class 'Album\Controller\AlbumController' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJ3C.png)i'm trying to add a new module named as `Album` in Zend Skeleton application but however while accessing it through URL it throws an error below.i have spent almost 5 hours but did not find any solution.Any help will be appreciated.

> File:/var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/InvokableFactory.php:30
>
> Message:Class Album/Controller/AlbumController not found.
>
> stack trace
>       #0 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>       servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(758): 
>       Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory-
>   __invoke(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 
>        'Album\Controlle...', NULL)
>        #1 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>        servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(200): 
>       Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Album\Controlle...')
>       #2 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>        servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(141): 
>        Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Album\Controlle...')
>        #3 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>        mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(95): 
>        Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Album\Controlle...')
>        #4 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>        eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener-
>   onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>        #5 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>        eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): 
>       Zend\EventManager\EventManager-
>   triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>        #6 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zend-
>         mvc/src/Application.php(332): Zend\EventManager\EventManager-
>   triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>        #7 /var/www/zf2-tutorial/public/index.php(48): Zend\Mvc\Application-
>   run()
>        #8 {main}

```
**module.config.php**
<?php
namespace Album;

  return array(
  'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => Controller\AlbumController::class

    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => Controller\Album::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),

            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
);
 ?>


**AlbumController.php**
<?php
namespace Album;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $albumTable;
public function getAlbumTable()
{
    if (! $this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    }
    return $this->albumTable;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'albums' => '',
    ));
}

public function addAction()
{

}

public function editAction()
{

}

public function deleteAction()
{

}

}


**Album.php**
 <?php
namespace Album\Model;

class Album
{

public $id;

public $artist;

public $title;

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id = (! empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->artist = (! empty($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : 
     null;
    $this->title = (! empty($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
 } 
 }

 **AlbumTable.php**
<?php
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AlbumTable
{

protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}

public function getAlbum($id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array(
        'id' => $id
    ));
    $row = $rowset->current();
    if (! $row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row;
}

public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
{
    $data = array(
        'artist' => $album->artist,
        'title' => $album->title
    );

    $id = (int) $album->id;
    if ($id == 0) {
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    } else {
        if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
            $this->tableGateway->update($data, array(
                'id' => $id
            ));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Album id does not exist');
        }
    }
}

public function deleteAlbum($id)
{
    $this->tableGateway->delete(array(
        'id' => (int) $id
    ));
  }
  }

   **Module.php**
<?php
 namespace Album;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
 u    se Album\Model\Album;
 use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
 use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, 
 ConfigProviderInterface
   {

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__
            )
        )

    );
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';

}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
     return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Album\Model\AlbumTable' => function ($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new 
              Album());
                return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, 
     $resultSetPrototype);
            }
        )
    );
}
public function getControllerConfig()
 {
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\AlbumController::class => function($container) 
  {
                return new Controller\AlbumController(
                    $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                    );
            },
            ],
            ];
  }
 }


  ?>
 **composer.json**


{
"name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description" : "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc 
 applications",
"type" : "project",
"license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords" : [
    "framework",
    "mvc",
    "zf"
],
"homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/",
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
"require" : {
    "php" : "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "zendframework/zend-component-installer" : "^1.0 || ^0.7 || 
 ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc" : "^3.0.1",
    "zfcampus/zf-development-mode" : "^3.0"
},
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Application\\" : "module/Application/src/"

 }
},
"autoload-dev" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "ApplicationTest\\" : "module/Application/test/"
    }
},
"extra" : {
    "zend-skeleton-installer" : [{
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-developer-tools",
            "constraint" : "^1.1.0",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install the developer 
   toolbar?",
            "module" : true,
            "dev" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-cache",
            "constraint" : "^2.7.1",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install caching support?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-db",
            "constraint" : "^2.8.1",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install database support 
    (installs zend-db)?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-mvc-form",
            "constraint" : "^1.0",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install forms support?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-json",
            "constraint" : "^3.0",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install JSON 
     de/serialization support?"
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-log",
            "constraint" : "^2.9",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install logging support?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-mvc-console",
            "constraint" : "^1.1.10",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install MVC-based console 
  support? (We recommend migrating to zf-console, symfony/console, or 
  Aura.CLI)",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n",
            "constraint" : "^1.0",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install i18n support?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins",
            "constraint" : "^1.0.1",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install the official MVC 
  plugins, including PRG support, identity, and flash messages?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge",
            "constraint" : "^0.2.2",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to use the PSR-7 middleware 
   dispatcher?"
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-session",
            "constraint" : "^2.7.1",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install sessions support?",
            "module" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-test",
            "constraint" : "^3.0.1",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install MVC testing 
     support?",
            "dev" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "zendframework/zend-servicemanager-di",
            "constraint" : "^1.0",
            "prompt" : "Would you like to install the zend-di 
  integration for zend-servicemanager?",
            "module" : true
        }
    ]
  },
"scripts" : {
    "cs-check" : "phpcs",
    "cs-fix" : "phpcbf",
    "development-disable" : "zf-development-mode disable",
    "development-enable" : "zf-development-mode enable",
    "development-status" : "zf-development-mode status",
    "post-create-project-cmd" : "@development-enable",
    "serve" : "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php",
    "test" : "phpunit"
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the full path (including filename) to your album controller?

Comment: zf2-tutorial.localhost/album @TimFountain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems within your configuration.

You should change the way you register your controllers. It is now only registered as an invokable with the string you've given. It is not registered by its FQCN as you try to use it within your route configuration. Nevertheless you use the wrong FQCN within the route config. You are using `Controller\Album::class` but the class is called: `AlbumController` so change that to `Controller\AlbumController::class`.

This is what your config should've been looking like:

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => Controller\AlbumController::class
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            Controller\AlbumController::class => \Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory::class,
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),

                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

As we've registered an alias you can replace the controller option within the route defaults. You can thus use `'Album\Controller\Album'` instead of the FQCN, but I rather use the FQCN within configurations. As it is easier to maintain your code.

One next thing you might bump into is that you are trying to use `getServiceLocator()` within your controller but this is no longer supported. Check this out: [ZendFramework: ServiceManager - Factories](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/configuring-the-service-manager/#factories)

Comment: thanx for replying..i have tried this but still getting the same error. @Kwido

Comment: So what is the error you received when you tried this? You might aswell need to check your composer.json PSR-4 autoloading. As `"Album\\": "module/Album/src/"` is not right, due to the fact that you have a folder under it with the name "Album". If so your namespaces are basically `Album\Album\Controller\AlbumController` Place all your files directly in the src folder and move your `module.php` class within the SRC folder as well and generate your composer autoloading. See if this is the problem. Or just point composer to the "module/Album/src/Album/" folder.

Comment: first i was receiving this error  "Class Album/Controller/AlbumController not found".but after changing i got Controller/AlbumController not found.

Comment: Can your `Album\Controller\AlbumController` be autoloaded or found by the composer autoloading? Can you check that?

Comment: No it is not found by the composer.

Comment: i have linked the other files can you kindly take a look on it?? @Kwido

Comment: You are not autoloading your Album module folder. Add `"Album\\" : "module/Album/src/"` after: `"Application\\" : "module/Application/src/"` in your composer.json within PSR-4 autoloading. As your controller can not be autoloaded it throws an error that the class is not found. And from the screenshot you've provided, you should move all the files within your Album src folder one folder up so they're directly attached to the src folder instead of the src/album folder.

Comment: Thank u soo much for your kind response.God bless you. :)